# Does Mathematica work on 2016 MacBook Pros?

Tags: mac-os-x, version-11

I ordered a new MacBook Pro with the touch bar, but before I retire my current laptop I'd like to know if v11.0.1 is stable on it.

Has anyone got it working? If so, what is the user experience like with the touch bar?

Comment: I have a 2016 13" MacBook Pro and 11.0x and 11.x run just fine on it in OSX 10.12.x. Mine is without touch bar, but running https://red-sweater.com/touche suggests MMA does not take advantage of it – no custom controls appear with MMA.

Comment: Related: In 12.0, there is a "New Document" button in the Touch Bar.  In addition, it is possible to make your own functions that utilize the Touch Bar.

For example:


`n = 1;`

`controls = Select[ControllerState[n, "Controls"], StringStartsQ["X"]];`

`GetStates[] :=`

`Clip[Sort@`

`Rescale[DeleteCases[ControllerState[n, controls], -1.], {-0.75,`

 `0.32}, {0, 1}], {0, 1}] Dynamic[`

`Plot[Evaluate[Sin[(1 + GetStates[]) \[Pi] x]], {x, -Pi/2, Pi/2}]]`


Credit to SGHuisman from Twitch.

A more general example for the uses of this, just type:
`Dynamic[ControllerState[]]`