# Will (does) Mathematica support the Touch Bar on the Macbook Pro?

Tags: interface, hardware

I am considering purchasing a new Macbook Pro sometime this year (2017), perhaps with Touch Bar.  Does Wolfram plan to support it? Occurs to me that Mathematica's interactive and predictive notebook-interface might be a good fit with Touch Bar.

Comment: Oh, just imagine all the new bugs and crashes we can enjoy with this! Seriously though, this is not an official Wolfram forum, so I don't think you have a high chance of getting an answer here. I suggest you contact Wolfram directly about this -- and feel free to post an answer to your own question relating whatever they say.

Comment: Related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/131144/403

Comment: I had hoped SE-Mathematica had dropped the "requires Wolfram support" condition now that Wolfram employees often post openly: Wouldn't it be nice to not have to monitor two separate sites? SE readers that didn't want this content could apply a filter.

Comment: In terms of Touch Bar, I was thinking that it might be nice to slide with each hand separately to see dynamic two-variable dependencies—can't do that with a mouse.  I think this is what DJs use Touch Bar for.  On the other hand, Oleksandr R is probably right about the implementation-complexity: The world doesn't want front-end crashes.

Comment: Related: In 12.0, there is a "New Document" button in the Touch Bar.  In addition, it is possible to make your own functions that utilize the Touch Bar.

For example:


`n = 1;`

`controls = Select[ControllerState[n, "Controls"], StringStartsQ["X"]];`

`GetStates[] :=`

`Clip[Sort@`

`Rescale[DeleteCases[ControllerState[n, controls], -1.], {-0.75,`

 `0.32}, {0, 1}], {0, 1}] Dynamic[`

`Plot[Evaluate[Sin[(1 + GetStates[]) \[Pi] x]], {x, -Pi/2, Pi/2}]]`


Credit to SGHuisman from Twitch.

A more general example for the uses of this, just type:
`Dynamic[ControllerState[]]`

Comment: Try this to get an understanding of what I'm saying.  Note: you may need to change the value of `n` to get this to work on your machine:
`n = 2;`
`Dynamic[# -> ControllerState[n, #] & /@`
  `ControllerState[n, "Controls"]]`

Comment: How is this off-topic?